# Change value on mouse move, three.js

Tags: three.js, onmousemove

I have this sphere 
`var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 50,  64,  32 );`
And I want to create a fonction like 
`function onMouseMove(event){
    mouseX = (event.clientX - window.innerWidth/2) / window.innerWidth/2;
    mouseY = (event.clientY - window.innerHeight/2) / window.innerHeight/2;
}`

To get `SphereGeometry( 50,  MouseX*64,  MouseY*32 )`

But I can't find the right way to write this.. 
Can somebody help me, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Change the position of your mesh, and rerender it.

```
mesh.position.x = x;
mesh.position.y = y;
mesh.position.z = z;
```

You can use events to bind your mousemove:

```
canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove, true);
```